# LS Agent to process selected documents from xpage

Tags: xpages, lotusscript

I would like to offer users the ability to select multiple documents ( or a single doc) and click a button to call a LS agent to cycle thru those documents and do some processing.    I know i can send down a doc id ( as in a query save agent), but how to send an array, or a string of multiple values that I parse in the LS  agent?

TIA

Comment: Just to clarify, Is your button on XPages or Form which calls the agent to process? You have added xpages and lotusscript tag to your question that's why the question.

Comment: my button is on an XPAGE that contains the view control.

Comment: If you have view control on your XPage then why don't you write your code in SSJS? Have a look at this wiki - [**How to get the documents selected in a View panel in Xpage**](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/2008-11-11033022WEBBZ4.htm).

Comment: You can make dummy document with all UNIDs in multivalue field and pass it to agent by runWithDocumentContext: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_and_Calling_Agents_Using_an_In-Memory_Document

Comment: Naveen - My pref is to reuse some LS code that already exists.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth - ok - i like this idea- however, getting error of Unexpected error:
NotesAgent.runWithDocumentContext(lotus.domino.local.Document) null

Comment: You *really* want to revisit your preferences. Let me translate: I prefer not to spend time on fast code and rather have the user spend time waiting for the agent subsystem to initialize every time they hit the button. What happened to: The needs of the many out-weight the needs of the few?

Comment: Regarding "Unexpected error: NotesAgent.runWithDocumentContext(lotus.domino.local.Document) null" it is minor, but common problem: you need to set agent's property "Run as web user".

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments.  I choose the path of SSJS and am almost finished with code.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XPage, you can use a temporary document to pass values as you like to your agent:

```
var agent = database.getAgent("myagent");
var doc = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("docIDs", <your array with IDs>);
agent.runWithDocumentContext(doc)
```

and in the agent

```
dim session as new notesSession
dim tmpdoc as notesDocument
set tmpdoc = session.documentContext
dim array as variant
array = tmpdoc.docIDs
```

Note that you don't need to save the temporary document at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the LS agent run against a certain criteria like all entries in a certain view and that view selects all documents with a field to mark the document to be processed, then have a repeat control with a checkbox that will add a value to a field on the document to mark the document for processing. This value will be used in the view selection criteria. You can then run the LS agent on this view on a schedule. You will then need to mark the documents as processed as well when you finish running the agent to remove them from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution: if (reaction) speed is not essential, you can send your own application a mail. There is the additional overhead, plus the Mail-in Database document that you need, but the advantage is that it's all very transparent and you can use it for many other purposes.